# How do I separate two genders from the same column and use them separately?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where one column has the genders (M,F,O) and I have another column for patient_weight, I need to get the average weight of the Females and then show a count of all the males that weigh less than the average female. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT top 50 * 
FROM 
    dbo.patients

SELECT
    AVG(patient_weight)
FROM 
    patients
WHERE gender LIKE 'F';

SELECT
COUNT
    (patient_weight)
FROM 
    patients
WHERE gender LIKE 'M' AND patient_weight < 77
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `GROUP BY`, which would let your aggregate functions (`AVG` and `COUNT`) operate on _groups_ of data, instead of the whole selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the query with the female average weight will return a scalar value. you can use it directy as criteria for the weight of the male patients

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) number_of_malepatients_below_avg
FROM 
    patients
WHERE gender LIKE 'M' AND patient_weight < (SELECT
    AVG(patient_weight)
FROM 
    patients
WHERE gender LIKE 'F');
```

Comment: Thats exactly it! Thank you so much for the help, I tried doing the same WHERE statement but I didnt know you had to but it in brackets hahaha

Comment: Wouldn't it be more performatic if the subquery was a join? I mean having it in the where section would make the system to re-execute the query for every 'M' row? I know for sure it does that when a subquery is at the select section but don't recall whats the behaviour for the where section.

Comment: @JorgeCampos some users tested subqueries against joins with huge databases and their experience, was that they are equal in perfomance

Comment: @JorgeCampos SQL Server is perfectly capable of transforming a subquery into a join or vice versa in the vast majority of cases, so it makes little difference.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use window functions. I would only advise this if you have no indexing on the base table, as the subquery version provided by @nbk will probably be faster otherwise.

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) MaleBelowAvgFemaleWeight
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN patient_weight END) OVER () AS AvgFemaleWeight
    FROM patients p
) p
WHERE gender = 'M' AND patient_weight < AvgFemaleWeight;
```